# Where are the explanations to warnings of VS 2005 Code Analyses tool?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, code-analysis

Does anyone know where to find an explanation to the warnings in VS 2005 Code Analyses tool. I would like some documentation, explaining why it creates the warnings it does and what course of action one should take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right click the warnings it gives you in the Error List and view Error Help, right from within Visual Studio.  There's also a [section of MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee1hzekz(VS.80).aspx), if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which codeanalysis tool you are referring to.

If you mean FxCop, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429379(VS.80).aspx

If you mean StyleCop, see the download here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1425